# declareUpdate in JavaScript calling XQuery in MarkLogic 8

Tags: marklogic

I try to use the function declareUpdate();
I copy/paste the code from the manual and I get the following error message.

There must be something about this that I am missing. I've added the declareUpdate because of this error:

```
{error: "XDMP-UPDATEFUNCTIONFROMQUERY: xdmp.apply(create-source#3, "CS_wifi.json", "cswifi", {"getId":{}, "findSource":{}, "createSourceWithMap":{}, "buildSo...}) -- Cannot apply an update function from a query"}
```

With the declareUpdate I get this:

```
{
  "errorResponse": {
    "statusCode": 400,
    "status": "Bad Request",
    "messageCode": "JS-JAVASCRIPT",
    "message": "JS-JAVASCRIPT: declareUpdate(); -- Error running JavaScript request: Operation not allowed on the currently executing transaction with identifier declareUpdate"
  }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * @name vriendingest 
 * This REST extentsion provides SOAP service for the shipment data
 */

declareUpdate();

var eput   = require("/MarkLogic/rest-api/lib/endpoint-util.xqy");
var link   = require("/ext/obi/lib/link-lib.xqy");
var object = require("/ext/obi/lib/object-service-lib.xqy", "/ext/obi/lib/object-lib.xqy");
var source = require("/ext/obi/lib/source-lib.xqy");

function post(context, params, input) {
    try {
      xdmp.log('title')
      xdmp.log(params.title);

      testing  = source.buildUri('takethisuri');
      title    = params.title;
      dataset  = "cswifi";
      sourceId = source.createSource(title, dataset, source);

      xdmp.log(sourceId);

   response = '{success: "' + testing + '"}';
   }
   catch(err){
      response = '{error: "' + err + '"}';
   }
   context.outputTypes = ["application/xml"];
   context.outputStatus = [200, "OK"];

   return response;
}

// Main
exports.POST = post;
```

Comment: Hello did the below solution work, because I'm using PUT function instead of post but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: yes for me it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POST calls to extension get the query mode by default. With XQuery you can add a annotation to the POST function to change that, but there is no annotation for ServerSide JavaScript. You best switch to PUT method..

HTH!